# ¿Configurar proxy con NGINX?

Tags: servidor, nginx, proxy

Me gustaría configurar NGINX para que el tráfico que entra por http://www.dominio.com/ruta/ vaya a una dirección http://nombre.equipo/carpeta/.

¿Sería correcta esta implementación?, o ¿necesitaría más parámetros de configuración?:

```
location /ruta/ {
    proxy_pass    http://nombre.equipo/carpeta/;
}
```

Comment: Me faltan detalles: Quieres mandar todo el tráfico a `http://nombre.equipo/carpeta/`, donde hay otro servidor web?

Comment: A no ser que quieras cambiar los valores por defecto de tiempos de espera, la configuración la tienes correcta. Una URL del tipo `http://www.dominio.com/ruta/pepito.html` sería pasado al servidor remoto como `http://nombre.equipo/carpeta/pepito.html`. Ten en cuenta que la IP fuente que verá el último servidor será la del servidor nginx. Si no quieres que sea así deberás hacer uso de [`proxy_set_header`] en nginx y [`remoteip`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html) si es un apache el destino (o equivalente dependiendo del servidor) para recuperar la IP original.

Comment: @PabloLozano sí, por ejemplo nombre.equipo/carpeta es una aplicación desplegada en IIS, me gustaría redirigir el tráfico a esta aplicación cuando se accede al dominio.com/ruta/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo tengo configurado para varios servicios en mi Pi y al menos a mi para que me funciona, la configuración ha sido algo más compleja, te dejo un ejemplo de cómo tengo el proxy configurado para que cuando entre a la url "admin.nombredemidominio.com" me redireccione a una url local que es la de mi router:

```
# Router Admin Page
#server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name admin.nombredemidominio.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:80;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true; proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

En tu caso, deberías de cambiar el `server_name` por nombre.equipo/carpeta/ y la sentencia `proxy_pass` por http://www.dominio.com/ruta/.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: No sería al revés Juan? server.name = el nombre del dominio, y luego el proxy pass a nombre.equipo?

Comment: En realidad server_name ahí es un filtro: puedes tener varios dominios apuntando a la misma IP y nginx mostrará distintas aplicaciones según pongas uno u otro

Comment: Funciona tal y como dice Pablo, Pelayo, en éste caso server_name sería el nombre del dominio desde el que tendrá como base las peticiones en ese servidor y el proxy_pass, a que dirección se le redirigirán las peticiones.

Comment: por eso el nombre de virtualhost gracias al server name